# Changing imports for a contract that has been deployed

Tags: solidity, remix, import

I am very new to writing smart contracts and deployed one via remix.ethereum. However, during the process I imported the wrong dependency links and need to change them.

I know smart contracts are immutable but is there any possible work around to get new imports?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

No, as you have noted contracts are immutable, you can not change anything about them, including imports. You would have to re-deploy and migrate anything from your previous contract (like balances, mappings etc.) to the new one